# Has Saudi Arabia announced plans for a women-only city?

Tags: gender, sexism, saudi-arabia

There's been reports of announced plans for a women-only city in Saudi Arabia. For example: [Saudi Arabia plans new city for women workers only](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2012/aug/12/saudi-arabia-city-women-workers?newsfeed=true) from The Guardian.

[Al Arabiya](http://english.alarabiya.net/articles/2012/08/15/232445.html) claimed (on August 15, 2012) that the press release stated the city would not be for females only. This was mentioned in a [blog post](http://stream.aljazeera.com/story/saudi-women-only-city-look-again-0022319) on Al Jazeera.

Middle eastern media still seems to be talking about the press release as if it's for females only, based on [Women-only industrial cities welcomed](http://www.zawya.com/story/Saudi_Arabia_Womenonly_industrial_cities_welcomed-ZAWYA20120831052132/) (dated August 31, 2012).

Who's right?

Any announcements, past or present, of female-only cities in Saudi Arabia will be acceptable for this question.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't just come straight to TSE asking "How can I travel there?" XD

Comment: @Fiksdal because if something is too good to be true, it probably is!

Comment: how is the word "nekkid" not part of the equation here?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet because Saudi Arabia, that's why.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, Saudi Arabia has **not** announced plans for a women-only city.

The Guardian article only says that all the **workers** in the cities will be women. Not all the **residents**. And that's based on a misreading of the original press-release, which makes it clear that there will be opportunities for female and male entrepreneurs, female and male employees, and female and male residents.

The [original press release](http://www.modon.gov.sa/English/MediaCenter/News/Pages/ModonPlansDevelopmentWomenIC.aspx) from [MODON, the Saudi Industrial Property Authority](http://www.modon.gov.sa/English/Pages/default.aspx), that the news outlets based their articles on, says (my emphasis):

> MODON begins Planning and Development for the First Industrial City being readied for Women in the Kingdom
>
> Al-Ahsa 2nd Industrial City will create **job opportunities for both men and women**
>
> MODON has initiated works for planning and development of the first industrial city being readied for women workers in the Kingdom. It will be launched in Al-Ahsa 2nd Industrial city which is located in Hofuf near Al-Ahsa airport.
>
> According to preliminary studies, the area allocated for Al-Ahsa 2nd will accommodate approximately 50 industrial projects. MODON will provide land at discounted rates to **businessmen and businesswomen** to establish their industrial or service projects. They will have the option to choose the type of industry on specific terms of preservation of the environment and safety of workers. **Special sections and production halls will be reserved for women within the factory, i. e, the city is not closed or not intended for women only.**