# Are bikinis banned from the 2013 Miss World competition in Indonesia?

Tags: culture

The Sun newspaper [reported](http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/4957677/Bikinis-axed-from-Miss-World-in-bid-to-avoid-Muslim-threats.html#ixzz2VTINVIJr):

> The pageant is taking place in the Far East country for the first time and organisers are wary of upsetting Muslim fanatics.
>
> [...]
>
> But the pageant's chairwoman Julia Morley said: "I do not want to upset or get anyone in a situation where we are being disrespectful.
>
> "We treasure respect for all the countries that take part in the pageant," she said.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, bikinis are banned from the 2013 Miss World contest.

Reference: [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/07/world/asia/a-more-wholesome-miss-world-pageant-this-year.html)

> [T]he billionaire organizer of the Miss World pageant declared Thursday that there would be no bikinis this year.

Comment: If these were all different sources, this would be good confirmation, but several - possibly all? - of these reports have been produced from the same Associate Press source, so they are merely repeats of the claim, not independent confirmations.

Comment: See also http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/has-saudi-arabia-announced-plans-for-a-woman-only-city for an example of an Islam-related false claim going viral and being repeated in several sources.

Comment: It's not that I doubt their accuracy. On the balance of probability, I would say they are likely correct. But this isn't a definitive answer. If the OP doesn't trust newspaper reports, this doesn't raise the quality of the evidence. (I can't edit away the duplicates because, for all I know, they are all duplicates of the same initial AP report.)

Comment: Okay, I included a story from the New York Times instead, that is not based on the AP report, and quotes the project director from the organizer of the competition.

Comment: @Oddthinking if OP doesn't trust the Sun, I can't blame him. If the Sun's piece is confirmed by several other sources, independent from each other, it becomes a lot more plausible. I seriously doubt you're going to find a peer reviewed scientific study on this topic... And even those are often enough highly questionable.

Comment: @jwenting: I don't think a peer-reviewed source is required. A press-release, a copy of the competition rules, photos from the actual event, an interview that is clearly NOT from the Associated Press - all would be independent sources.

Comment: That confirms it not scheduled: not that it's "banned", or that "organisers are wary of upsetting Muslim fanatics".

Comment: @ChrisW If organizers of the event don't schedule something, then it's not going to happen. My answer doesn't address motivations, since the question didn't ask about motivations.

Comment: @Oddthinking that would be a change in the rules here as observed by most mods...

Comment: @Jwenting: I'm not clear on your point; sounds like something that would be best spelled out on meta.